# Kivy: How to add loading bar while updating recycleview table data?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Currently I have two screens, the first to upload a text file containing csv values and the second a table displaying these values. At the moment both my screens initiates at the same time and thus screen two has a empty recycleview table. I update this table using the refreshview() by getting access to the ExampleViewer() instance and updating the table.

The user selects the file and the data is loaded. I managed to get a loading bar working here using a thread. I want to add another loading bar for while the refreshview() updates the recycleview table. I tried doing this similar to the first loading bar method but it doesn't work

Here is code:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial
import threading
import csv

new_d = list()

def refreshview():
        rvobj = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('scr2').ids.rv_list #main table
        if len(new_d) != 0:
            # rvobj.createview() ## for without following 3 lines of loading bar attempt
            pol = main_load()      
            pol.open()
            threading.Thread(target=rvobj.createview, args=(pol,)).start()

class Filechooser(BoxLayout): 
    lines = 0
    file_name = ''
    new_d = list()

    def select(self, filename):  
        try: 
            self.file_name = filename[0]
        except: pass
    def load(self):
        pop = progress_d()
        pop.open()
        threading.Thread(target=self.load_data, args=(pop,)).start()
    def load_data(self,obj):
        cnt = 0
        with open(self.file_name) as f:
                    self.lines = sum(1 for _ in f)
        obj.cnt.max = self.lines
        with open(self.file_name,'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                il = [s.strip() for s in line.split(',')]
                new_d.append(il)
                Clock.schedule_once(obj.update_progress)

class ExampleViewer(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for x in new_d:
            d = {'text': str(x),'color': (0,0,0,1) ,'on_press': partial(self.butt, x)}
            self.data.append(d)
    def butt(self, x):
        print('button', x, 'pressed')
    def createview(self,obj):
        for x in new_d:
            d = {'text': str(x),'color': (0,0,0,1) ,'on_press': partial(self.butt, x)}
            self.data.append(d)
            Clock.schedule_once(obj.update_progress) ## also remove for without loading bar attempt

class progress_d(Popup):
    cnt = ObjectProperty(None)
    def update_progress(self,dt):
        self.cnt.value +=1
        if (self.cnt.value/self.cnt.max) == 1:
            self.dismiss()

class custPop_start(Popup):   # filechoose popup window
    pass
class main_load(Popup):
    cnt1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    def update_progress(self,dt):
        self.cnt1.value +=1
        if (self.cnt1.value/self.cnt1.max) == 1:
            self.dismiss()

class load_screen(Screen):
    def open_popup(self):
        the_popup = custPop_start()
        the_popup.open()
    def refresh(self):
        refreshview()
class display_screen(Screen):
    pass

class SampleApps(App): 
    def build(self):  
        root = ScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(load_screen(name='scr1'))
        root.add_widget(display_screen(name='scr2'))
        return root

if __name__=='__main__':
# run the App 
    l = SampleApps()
    l.run()
```

And here is kv file:

```
<display_screen>:
    id: scr2
    orientation: 'vertical'
    FloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.3,'top':1}
        size_hint: 0.6,0.5
        Label:
            text: 'DATA'
            size_hint: 1,0.1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'top':1}
        ExampleViewer:
            id: rv_list
            size_hint: 1,0.9
            pos_hint: {'x':0,'y':0}

<load_screen>:
    id: scr1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 0.3,0.4
        Label:
            text: "Read_file"
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
        Button:
            size_hint: 1,0.3
            back_color: 1,0,0,1
            text: "UPLOAD"
            on_press: root.open_popup()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1,0.3
            back_color: 1,0,0,1
            text: "ANALYSE"
            on_press: root.refresh()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1,0.3
            back_color: 1,0,0,1
            text: "Screen2"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'scr2'

<custPop_start>:
    size_hint: 0.4,0.4
    pos_hint: {'x':0.5,'y':0.5}
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "the popup"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Filechooser:
            id: pie
            size_hint: 1, 0.8
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: 'LOAD'
            on_press: pie.load()
            on_release: root.dismiss()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1,0.1
            text: 'CANCEL' 
            on_press: root.dismiss()

<ExampleViewer>: 
    id: btn2
    viewclass: 'Button' # defines the viewtype for the data items. 
    RecycleBoxLayout: 
        color:(0, 0, 0, 1) 
        default_size: None, dp(35)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        size_hint_x: 4
        height: self.minimum_height 
        width: self.minimum_width
        orientation: 'vertical' # defines the orientation of data items 

<Filechooser>:  
    id: Filechooser
    orientation: 'vertical' 
    BoxLayout: 
        orientation: 'vertical'
        FileChooserListView:
            id: file1 
            on_selection: Filechooser.select(file1.selection) 
<progress_d>: 
    cnt : my_progress
    size_hint: 0.3,0.3
    auto_dismiss: False
    BoxLayout: 
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ProgressBar:
            id: my_progress
            min: 0
            max: 1
            pos_hint: {'x':0.1}
            size_hint_x: 0.8
<main_load>: 
    cnt1 : my_progress1
    size_hint: 0.5,0.3
    auto_dismiss: False
    BoxLayout: 
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ProgressBar:
            id: my_progress1
            min: 0
            max: 1
            pos_hint: {'x':0.1}
            size_hint_x: 0.8
```

I try to add a loading bar while data updates by using another thread. But i get the error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:/Users/Llion/Desktop/TFR CS9()/logfile app/projek_app/pies.py", line 99, in <module>
     l.run()
   File "c:\Users\Llion\Desktop\TFR CS9()\logfile app\projek_app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "c:\Users\Llion\Desktop\TFR CS9()\logfile app\projek_app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "c:\Users\Llion\Desktop\TFR CS9()\logfile app\projek_app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "c:\Users\Llion\Desktop\TFR CS9()\logfile app\projek_app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 399, in idle
     Clock.tick_draw()
   File "c:\Users\Llion\Desktop\TFR CS9()\logfile app\projek_app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 783, in tick_draw
     self._process_events_before_frame()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 658, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 701, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 697, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "c:\Users\Llion\Desktop\TFR CS9()\logfile app\projek_app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\recycleview\__init__.py", line 225, in refresh_views        
     lm.compute_sizes_from_data(data, f)
   File "c:\Users\Llion\Desktop\TFR CS9()\logfile app\projek_app\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\recyclelayout.py", line 133, in compute_sizes_from_data     
     assert len(data) == len(opts)
 AssertionError
```

So my question is how can I get a loading bar working while updating the data and is there possibly a better way to update the table data or possibly only initiate the table screen once the data is loaded?

can please just create a text file with rows of csv data to use for testing. My csv data files is ussually around 22mb and thats why i need loading bars it takes a while to upload and update. Thank you

Comment: Is that the entire stacktrace?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Hi I uploaded the full stack trace now

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error using your posted code. To your actual question, are you accessing the `.csv` file over the network? When I run your code and select a 300MB `.csv` file, the progress bar appears and is dismissed so quickly that it seems pointless. If your progress bar gets dismissed quickly enough, it may not even appear. Are you sure you need progress bars?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Wow okay then my pc is way slower than I thought. Maybe not then. Just one more thing. Is the way I update the recycleview data a good one? It feels there might be a better way?